# Explanation of PyAPI_DATA() macro?

Tags: python, c, api, python-c-api

I've searched all over the web and [can't seem to find](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Adocs.python.org%2Fc-api+PyAPI_DATA&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) documentation or even a simple explanation of what PyAPI_DATA() does (even though it is [used in the Python header files](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/tupleobject.h) and [cited on python.org](http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/whatsnew/node20.html)). Could anyone care to explain what this is or point me to documentation I am overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used to mark public API variables (as Python's core is usually a dynamic library), e.g. on Windows, it's expanded to `extern __declspec(dllexport) RTYPE` when core is compiled and to `extern __declspec(dllimport) RTYPE` when e.g. modules are compiled. It's defined in `Include/pyport.h`.